# Where is my mistake? U-Substitution

Tags: integration, substitution

I'm learning about U-Substitution and I'd like to know where is my mistake in this exercise.
I recognize that have a easier  way, which is u=tag x substitution. But I would like to understand where the error lies in this resolution.

$\int \tan ^3x\cdot \sec ^2x\ dx=\int \frac{sin ^3x}{cos^ 3x}\cdot \frac{1}{cos^2x}\ dx \\ \int \tan ^3x\cdot \sec ^2x\ dx=-\int \frac{1-u^2}{u^5}\ du, u= \cos x \\ \int \tan ^3x\cdot \sec ^2x\ dx=\frac{1}{4\cos ^4x}-\frac{1}{2\cos ^2x}+C$

Comment: What makes you think there's an error in this resolution?

Comment: The right answer is 1/4 (tg x)^4 + C. I don't know if my answer matches this result.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Your answer matches the result. You can either differentiate both and see that they are both antiderivatives, or compute their difference and see that it's constant.

Comment: You are answer is correct. The book wants you to substitute $u= \tan x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4 \cos^4 x} - \frac{1}{2 \cos^2 x} &= \frac{(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)^2}{4 \cos^4 x} - \frac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{2 \cos^2 x}  \\
    &= \frac{\sin^4 x + 2 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x + \cos^4 x}{4 \cos^4 x} - \frac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x}{2 \cos^2 x}  \\
    &= \frac{\sin^4 x}{4 \cos^4 x} + \frac{2 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x}{4 \cos^4 x} + \frac{\cos^4 x}{4 \cos^4 x} - \frac{\sin^2 x}{2 \cos^2 x} - \frac{\cos^2 x}{2 \cos^2 x}  \\
    &= \frac{\sin^4 x}{4 \cos^4 x} + \frac{\sin^2 x}{2 \cos^2 x} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\sin^2 x}{2 \cos^2 x} - \frac{1}{2 }  \\
    &= \frac{\sin^4 x}{4 \cos^4 x} + \frac{-1}{4}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{4}\tan^4 x + \frac{-1}{4}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Of course, the $-1/4$ can be absorbed into the constant of integration.

Comment: Probably easier would be to write $\sin^4(x) = (1 - \cos^2(x))^2 = 1 - 2\cos^2(x) + \cos^4(x)$ and expand $\frac{1}{4}\tan^4(x)$ instead.

Comment: @Rushy : Possibly...  But there's nothing actually hard here except, possibly, for squaring the first use of the trigonometric Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Thanks you both!